# Why cant I add two methods to a class using v-bind

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Using vue.js 2 I need to dynamically add classes to a <tr> element.

**What works (single method call)**

```
:tbody-tr-class="urgentEnquiryMixin_rowColour"
```

****What doesn't work** (two method calls, one a mixin)**

Adding an additional method to the v-bind

```
:tbody-tr-class="urgentEnquiryMixin_rowColour applyUnreadClass"
```

**What i have tried**

```
:tbody-tr-class="[applyUnreadClass, urgentEnquiryMixin_rowColour]"

:tbody-tr-class="{applyUnreadClass(), urgentEnquiryMixin_rowColour}"
```

**Additional code for info**

```
applyUnreadClass(item, type) {
    if (!item || type !== 'row') {
        return '';
    }
    if (item.read === false) {
        return 'unread-email-row';
    }
    return '';
}

urgentEnquiryMixin_rowColour(item, type) {
    if (!item || type !== 'row') { return ''; }
    if (item.isUrgent === true) { return 'tr-urgent'; }
    return '';
}

<b-table id="assigned-enquiries-table" class="index-grid" headVariant="light" hover
    :items="enquiriesData" :fields="columns" :current-page="page" :per-page="rowsPerPage"
    show-empty :tbody-tr-class="applyUnreadClass, urgentEnquiryMixin_rowColour"
    @filtered="onFiltered" :busy="isBusy"
    >
```

**Errors**

> 'v-bind' directives require an attribute value
> Parsing error: Unexpected token ','.
> Parsing error: Unexpected token ','.eslint-plugin-vue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use class directly for optional classes.

You can even use class as well to have classes that always work:

```html
<div
  class="static"
  :class="{ active: isActive, 'text-danger': hasError }"
></div>
```

So create props for these classes (which are booleans) and pass them like that to you.

However if you want to add them dynamically. Create ONE string that you paste inside class. This will contain all classes in that string. (eg. 'Class1 Class2 Class3')

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Adding :tbody-tr-class="{'tr-urgent': item.isUrgent}" causes  the following error - TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'isUrgent') any idea why i cant access "item"? Full element -   <b-table id="assigned-enquiries-table" class="index-grid" headVariant="light" hover
   :items="enquiriesData" :fields="columns" :current-page="page" :per-page="rowsPerPage"
   show-empty :tbody-tr-class="{'tr-urgent': item.isUrgent}"
   @filtered="onFiltered" :busy="isBusy"
   >

Comment: I guess because you use item as a parameter in your function instead of a data object. You have to define variables in your data function if you want to access them in whole your component.